# Wix Installer how do I create registry key if the user agrees to a dialog?

Tags: wix, registry, installation, user-input

I am creating an installer in Wix.
I need a simple dialog during the installation where the user has to agree something, if they do, I want to create a registry key recording this choice.

This seems the simplest of tasks, but how do I use Wix to create the dialog and conditionally create the registry key based on the user's input?

So far I've tried to find out about custom actions, but it seems that this is not the right tool as Wix contains the ability to create a registry key already.
I just don't know how to tie installation of a feature to the response to a specific dialog.
If the agreement is not given, then the installer should continue as normal, just without this specific registry key.

I'm using Visual Studio.

Some code snippets:
This is at the top of my product, next to the other properties.

```
<Property Id="STREAMING_ACCEPTED" Secure="yes"/>
```

Then I have a dialog with the following control element.

```
<Control Id="StreamingAcceptedCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="207" Width="330" Height="18" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="STREAMING_ACCEPTED" Text="Accept streaming" />
```

And finally, I'm trying to hook this up by adding a condition to the component.

```
<Component Id ="StreamingAcceptanceRegKey" Guid="some-guid" Win64="yes">
  <Condition>STREAMING_ACCEPTED</Condition>
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyProgram" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="UsageStats" Value="true" Action="write" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Am I on the right lines, because it's not writing the registry key? Does this actually record "true" and "false" to the property based on the checkbox state?

Comment: Do you allow the installation to continue if they don't agree?

Comment: Yes, it is literally one tiny feature inside the program that gets enabled if the registry key is present. The installation should otherwise continue as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI control has a property associated with it. Make sure it's a secure custom public property.  (All caps and marked secure ).

Describing how feature selection and INSTALLLEVEL works in an MSI takes some time.  Since you only have 1 registry value  I would instead suggest  creating a component  to set the registry value  and putting a condition on that component that uses the secure custom public property found in the UI.

If you want to support the user going into Programs and Features and changing the original choice then make sure you mark the component as transitive  and implement a WiX remember property pattern so that subsequent repairs / transactions  keep the choice.

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm much closer now. I now have a property in my main wxs file, all in block caps, and marked secure. I have a custom UI dialog, with a checkbox that (I think) is associated with this property. How do I "put a condition on the component" that uses this property?

Comment: You nest a condition element under the component element using this syntax.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/conditional-statement-syntax  https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html

Comment: I'm close... I just got pulled across to different issues, I hope to pick this back up again tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Working now, thanks! I would add that the checkbox sets the property if checked, and leaves it empty/null if unchecked, if anyone else is looking for this answer.